# Removing duplicate bones

Tags: armature, bones

Accidentally duplicated my bones and now there are two skeletons.  Is there a way to merge or delete the extra bones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your bones are named properly and uniquely, you can filter them by *Select Pattern*:

1. Go to 3D View menu, **Select** > **Select Pattern...**, then type '*.001', press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then delete them all.

[image]

Or you can target them by Outliner:

2. Select the Armature object, switch to Edit Mode, go to Outliner, set *Type* to Active, then search `.001` (the naming suffix to each duplicate and automatically given by Blender). Then <kbd>B</kbd> to select all bones, then go to 3D View, press <kbd>X</kbd>, choose *Delete Bones*.

[image]

If the methods above don't work well in your case, you can try **Select Similar** feature to select them quickly:

3. First, select the root bone, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>, choose *Children*, then delete them all. (For those with no children, usually you have to select them manually)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search in the Outliner Editor for `*.0*`

You can also go into edit mode and in the 3D View header-->Select-->Select pattern
and type `*.0*`

This should select the duplicates.

Comment: L (select linked) also works with armatures. selecting the root bone and pressing shift + ] multiple times will select all of it.

Comment: @root Sure, it works, but limited for branched skelton, e.g. it doesn't work well in my case. :)